# Overriding core model class (I did look at other answers ;) )

Tags: overrides, model

I want to override the core class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal

So following different tutorials I did this :

Lebernard is my namespace, Vente, my module

```
#Lebernard/Vente/etc/config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<config>
<modules>
    <lebernard_vente>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </lebernard_vente>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <quote_address_total_subtotal>Lebernard_Vente_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal</quote_address_total_subtotal>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </models>
</global>
</config>
```

Then I created the model which is suppose to override it by copying the core class. I want to change the **fetch** method.

```
#local/Lebernard/Vente/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Subtotal.php
class Lebernard_Vente_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal
{
   ...
}
```

And then I enabled the module

```
#etc/modules/Lebernard_Vente.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Lebernard_Vente>
        <active>true</active>
        <codepool>local</codepool>
    </Lebernard_Vente>
</modules>
</config>
```

No luck, the module is detected but the new class doesn't show up. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with "the module is detected"? How did you check it? Because with `<codepool>local</codepool>` (lowercase p) it cannot be loaded.

Comment: I mean that I can activate / desactivate the module in the backend

Comment: That's what I suspected. You can activate/deactivate *module output* and actually all modules that are defined in `app/etc/modules/` are listed there, even if they are not active or the code is missing or not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could either be that another module is rewriting the class before you. Check other `config.xml` files for that.

Or the class is called directly instead of via the `Mage` god class.

```
new Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal
```

vs

```
Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address_total_subtotal');
```

Next to that `codepool` should be with camel case, so `codePool` and the tag in `modules` too.

```
<modules>
    <Lebernard_Vente>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </Lebernard_Vente>
</modules>
[...]
```

Not sure if that is the direct cause of the issue but it might have negative effect :)

Comment: my money is on the `codePool` and on the modules subtag that should not be lowercase.

Comment: ahhh the times i've wasted minutes if not hours of my life on codepool...

Comment: change codepool to codePool, thanks, Lebernard_Vente was fine, stack formatted it. I've learn today :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have faced same problem in my going projects in sales->ordergrid .Ihave used below extension for which third party module is overriding

URL:http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/modules-conflict-detector.html

MySkype: kinex.sourav .join me

Email Address:kinexmediamagento@gmail.com